# unable to change the work space using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I try to create a folder and Geodatabase at the beginning of my code, so all results will be saved in it.
My code is:

```
class btn_WF(object):
        """Implementation for Addins_addin.button (Button)"""
        # this button allows the user to determine where he/she wants to store all output files
        # The model generates a folder called (), and a File GeoDataBase called ()
        # The model makes the generated GeoDataBase is the current workspace
        def __init__(self):
            self.enabled = True
            self.checked = False
        def onClick(self):
            import pythonaddins, arcpy
            # Let the user select a folder
            Work_Location = pythonaddins.OpenDialog("Please select a folder to store the project and files in", False, "C:/ModelBuilder/AAA","Select a Folder")
            # create a new folder to save the project in
            Project_Folder = arcpy.CreateFolder_management(Work_Location, "Flash Flood Risk Assessment Projcet")
            # create a GeoDataBase to store files and outputs
            Output_File_GDB=arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(Project_Folder, "FFRA_WRRI.gdb")

            # the problem is the next line
            # the "arcpy.env.workspace" doesnt accept to equal the variable "Output_File_GDB"
            arcpy.env.workspace = Output_File_GDB

            print (arcpy.env.workspace)
```

it gives me the follwoing error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 537, in set_
    self[env] = val
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 597, in __setitem__
    ret_ = setattr(self._gp, item, value)
RuntimeError: Object: Error in accessing environment <workspace>
```

Could you help me

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `print Work_Location` after setting it to see if it has the value you think?  Doing this with the Python window will let you see the output.

Comment: Here is a copy of all checks
 >>> print Work_Location
 C:\ModelBuilder\AAA\New Folder (8)
 >>> print Project_Folder
 C:\ModelBuilder\AAA\New Folder (8)\Flash Flood Risk Assessment Projcet
 >>> print Output_File_GDB
 C:\ModelBuilder\AAA\New Folder (8)\Flash Flood Risk Assessment Projcet\FFRA_WRRI.gdb

Comment: >>> arcpy.env.workspace = Output_File_GDB
 Runtime error 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 537, in set_
  self[env] = val
   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 597, in __setitem__
  ret_ = setattr(self._gp, item, value)
 RuntimeError: Object: Error in accessing environment <workspace>
 >>>

Comment: not necessarily the reason, but I would avoid blank spaces and special characters in my paths when working with ArcGIS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem before.

There are two solutions:

1. You need to set the result of the geoprocessing tool "CreateFileGDB" as a variable using arcpy.getOutput method.
2. Another way to set the GDB variable is to use the OS module.

Try:

```
result = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(Project_Folder, "FFRA_WRRI.gdb")
Output_File_GDB = result.getOutput(0)
arcpy.env.workspace = Output_File_GDB
```

or try:

```
import OS
Output_File_GDB = os.path.join(Project_Folder, "FFRA_WRRI.gdb")
arcpy.env.workspace = Output_File_GDB
```

Comment: When I print out 'result' and 'Output_File_GDB' the printed text is identical, what is the difference to arcpy?

Comment: As your setting the "result" variable as a geoprocessing tool, "result" does not then become the output. The variable is still the tool, rather than the output of the tool. By using the "result.getoutput", you are identifying the result of that tool and then setting a variable against that.